# ExtJs 4 and asp.net mvc 3 data load issue.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, extjs

I have problem with binding data from controller to store.

On JS side I have following code:

```
function buildGrid() {
    console.log("0");
    var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore(
    {
        url: '@Url.Content("~/Home/GridData")',
        root: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total',
        fields: ['Id', 'Name', 'State', 'Age']
    });
    console.log("1");
    store.load({ params: { start: 0, limit: 15} });
    console.log("2");
}
```

The controller code loks like:

```
public JsonResult GridData(int start, int limit)
{
    var contact = new List<Contact> {
        new Contact(){ Name= "Smith", State = "NU",  Age =24},
        new Contact(){ Name= "Adam", State= "LU", Age =32},
        new Contact(){ Name = "Eve", State= "WA", Age=18},
        new Contact(){ Name= "Chun Li", State="LI", Age=34}
    };
    return Json(new { total = contact.Count, data = contact, }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I can see 0 and 1 on FireBug console but instead of 2 i get an error:

```
url is undefined
 return url + (url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&') + s; 

ext-all-debug.js (line 5040)
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I havn't solved the problem however i did rid of the error by creating model.

```
Ext.define('Contact', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['Id', 'Name', 'State', 'Age']
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Contact',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'GridData',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            record: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here's the proxy I define on my store

```
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    batchActions: false,
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    },
    api: {
        create: 'CreateOrder.json',
        read: 'ReadOrder.json',
        update: 'UpdateOrder.json',
        destroy: 'DestroyOrder.json'
    },
    listeners: {
        exception: function (proxy, response, operation) {
            Ext.Msg.show({
                title: response.statusText,
                msg: Ext.decode(response.responseText).message,
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                icon: Ext.window.MessageBox.ERROR
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You could try out this library, which helps me
[extjs4efj](http://extjs4ef4.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score -3):

Maybe you should check [Dextop](http://dextop.codaxy.com/showcase/). It's an application framework completely dedicated to boost development of Ext/.NET based applications.